# Is this patent (US20060098849 A1) still pending?

Tags: application, patent-pending, us20060098849a1

I do not know how to tell if the patent application was accepted or declined.  I looked at the legal events on the Google Patents page but I don't understand what the information is saying.

Answer (score 3):

If you look in Public Pair you can see that it was abandoned in May 2009. That probably means the filer (or the filer's attorney, as the case may be) failed to respond to an office action.